# Treeview fill from text file value with hierarhy

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I read plain text file with three fields.
File with simple structure - name, tree_id, id.

Example

```
'NodeNameLevel0', 0, 1
'NodeNameLevel1', 1, 2
'NodeNameLevel2', 2, 3
'Value1', 3, 4
'Value2', 3, 5
'Value3', 3, 6
'NodeNameLevel2', 2, 7
'Value1', 7, 8
'Value2', 7, 9
'Value3', 7, 10
'Value4', 7, 11
```

expected tree some like this

```
'NodeNameLevel0'
    'NodeNameLevel1'
        'NodeNameLevel2'
            'Value1'
            'Value2'
            'Value3'
        'NodeNameLevel2'
            'Value1'
            'Value2'
            'Value3'
```

[image: example]

```
...
var
name: string;
tree_id, id: int;
// all strings step-by-step reading
while eof do
begin
//current string from file here
//split string and fill name, tree_id, id variable from file well done. 
//but what doing next ?

CREATE TREE HERE

end
...
```

Help me please create, and fill a TreeView with my structure.
I need little code for understand only.

Comment: The code you show is not actual code, it will not compile. Why don't you add the actual code you already have and show us where you are stuck. Then we can help you

Comment: @GuidoG yes, is not actual code, this just steps. 

If, suppose that I am in the variables I have the desired values from the file. I'm in a loop. How do I build a tree? I ask only one step in the iteration

delphi\pascal is not my preferred language. I noob and stuck at the fill a treeview node.